# Call module on needed page Opencart

Tags: opencart2.x

How to call module in Opencart 2.0 using his "ID"? I need to view the some modules not different places, I try find solution in google but no luck.

Comment: Can you give more details? what you are looking for? which module? and where you want to show it?

Comment: I have module with groups of products. This groups created in admin panel like module. I find example how to show all this groups, but I need show groups with needed ID. (Sorry for my bad English)

Answer (score 0):

Put this one in your controller.

`$data['anyvar'] = $this->load->controller('module/your-module-id');`

And in your view file just echo it. like,

`<?php echo $anyvar; ?>`